# Current googlemaps location using c#

Tags: c#, google-maps

Im trying to find an example of current location in Lat and Long using server side c# and NOT javascript? For instance in javascript it is as easy as this:

```
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
                return new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
            })
        };
```

Can someone provide me with an example just using c#?

Comment: If you want to use C# on the server side you need to just call the API endpoints and/or use a library like https://github.com/maximn/google-maps

Comment: Have you considered using javascript html page as return request to c# ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `Reverse Geocoding` ([details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding)). Google provides special service, which you can call by request and in response get data you need. [There is how to do request.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding)

Comment: Thats not what im looking for, I cant be any clearer